# Angular material components not getting displayed when dynamically loaded

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have used angular component  in jquery datatable but it is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please supply more data? code?
In general, using jQuery with Angular is really not recommended.
jQuery runs outside the cycle of Angular and therefor does not update.

if you wanna keep using jQuery you should trigger the change detector ref.

Inject the following in your component constructor

```
constructor(
    ...
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ...
)
```

after you generate the table, add the following line of code

```
this.cd.detectChanges();
```

Again, I highly recommend using angular component & packages only

Hope this helps!